# How to do a query that is agnostic of the sort field?

Tags: sql, sorting

I have multiple tables that have the same date_time added field in each table.  After doing a UNION of all tables i want to sort them by the most recent one.  But the query will tell me that the i have to add a table name like videos.date_time rather than ORDER BY date_time.  How can i structure the query so that it is agnostic of the which date_time field?

Comment: Some sample of your SQL would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are using a proprietary feature such as SQL Server's TOP directive, the Order By in a Union query is always at the bottom and always applies to the entire query. E.g.

```
Select Col1, date_time
From Table1
Union All
Select Col1, date_time
From Table2
Order By date_time
```

If your query does include various elements such TOP or LIMIT which require an Order By and thus you want to differentiate the Order By's, then you can encapsulate your query into a derived table:

```
Select Col, date_time
From    (
        Select Col1 As Col, date_time
        From Table1
        Union All
        Select Col1, date_time
        From Table2
        ) As Z
Order By Z.date_time
```

Comment: this is what i get: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns so i guess the tables need to have exactly the same number of columns?  I am going to my night job now when i come back i will post udpates! thanks thomas!

Comment: @KPO - In a union query, each query must return the same number of columns and each column in each position must be the same (or implicitly convertible) data type.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can also order by a column number, e.g. "ORDER BY 2" in which case whatever the second column is in your union set would be the sort target.

Comment: Technically true in the current and previous versions of SQL Server, but Microsoft has stated that they will stop supporting this feature in a future version.

Comment: @Thomas Ouch! I use that all the time (not in code, but in ad-hox queries)

Comment: Agreed with @geofftnz.  A good shortcut for ad hoc.  I am always skeptical of deprecation claims.  I think of them as trial-balloons.  Depending on how many people scream, these things might last forever.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have X tables (where X is > 1), and every table have it's own `date_time` column and you want to get last updated. If that's true, than one of the possible ways is to do it that way

```
SELECT id, date_added FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date_added FROM table2
ORDER BY date_added DESC;
```

Other ways which I have in mind is when you fetch results, put them in array and do the "magic" inside it.

Comment: @Thomas gave same example above while I tested mine :D